# Java - Access two or multiple specific indexes of an array

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way in Java to access two or more non-consecutive indexes of an array at the same time?

For example, I have the following array:

`int myArray = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}`

I know I can access one single index or consecutive indexes (using Arrays.copyOfRange) of this array. But if want to print out indexes 1 and 3 of this array; do I have to use the following:

`System.out.print(myArray[1] + myArray[3])`

I am expecting some syntax like the following; clearly, they are wrong

`System.out.print(myArray[1,3])`

or

`int indexes = {1,3}`

`System.out.print(myArray[indexes])`

Comment: `System.out.print(myArray[1] + myArray[3])` - Is this attempt failing in some way?  It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: Nope, no such syntax in Java.

Comment: Why would you expect a variable declared to hold a single `int` to be able to hold multiple `int`s?

Comment: What you seem to be referring to is known as a `slice` in some languages; Java is not one of them.

Comment: Btw, `Arrays.copyOfRange` doesn't let you access "consecutive indexes", it creates a *copy* of the provided array in a range (hence the name of the method). So you're creating a subarray that you'll have to access element-wise just like in your working example.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I think Scott pointed out exactly what I was trying to say as I am new to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to access different indices "at once", but you can easily print multiple values:

```
System.out.printf("%d, %d", myArray[1], myArray[3])
```